# Docusign - How to select a template and bulk send?

Tags: docusignapi

On the Docusign site it is possible to select a template, then upload a bulk list CSV file.  How is this done with the REST API or Net Libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. We document it here. https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/bulk-send-envelopes/